# Why arrow functions is not memoized between renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

Can you explain me why handleClick function is always new?

```
function Foo() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }

  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that `Foo()` is also a JavaScript function that's been re-run on every render.

Inside of that function there's a statement that is:

`const handleClick = () => {...};`

Meaning: create a function and assign it to my recently created local variable `handleClick`. Thus, it will be recreated on every render.

The performance impact of that is usually close to zero. But if you need, you can optmize for that.

`const handleClick = useCallback(()=>{...},[dependencyArray]);`

If that function depends on variables that may change, you can add those to the `dependencyArray` and React will recreate that functions if one of them changes. Otherwise it will keep the same function from the last time it was created.

[From React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render)

> **Are Hooks slow because of creating functions in render?**
>
> No. In modern browsers, the raw performance of closures compared to classes doesn’t differ significantly except in extreme scenarios.

From: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

**useCallback()**

> Returns a memoized callback.
>
> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

Comment: Thank you for detailed response.
Am i right that when i'm using class components, i'm working with instance so the function won't change( handleClick as a method not inline function )?

Comment: Yes. I think you're right. I started learning React with classes, but since Hooks came around it got much better. I'm never going back to classes. **From React Hooks FAQ:** _Hooks avoid a lot of the overhead that classes require, like the cost of creating class instances and binding event handlers in the constructor._

Answer (score 4):

`() => { console.log('Click happened'); }` creates a new function.

You do nothing to preserve it between calls to the `Foo` function.

So every time `Foo` is called, you get a new function.

Answer (score 2):

Because every time you render `Foo`, it will create everything inside of it again.

```
// rendering Foo
function Foo() {
  const handleClick = () => {    // instantiated again
    console.log('Click happened');
  }

  const something...     // instantiated again

  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
}
```

To avoid `handleClick` to be instantiated again you can declare it outside of the component.

```
const handleClick = () => {    
  console.log('Click happened');
}
function Foo() {              
  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
}
```

Or if You really want that to be in scope of the function but not instantiated you could do like this

```
// rendering Foo
function Foo() {
  const handleClick = useCallback( // not re-defined again, uses old reference
    () => {
      console.log(`Click happened`);
    }
  );

  const something...     // instantiated again

  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
}
```

[Read about UseCallback here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)